# Q: how to calculate a slope with measurments error in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know much in python or math for that matter but I need to use it for an assignment. I am trying to calculate the slope of a graph and I need to include the error (STD) in the calculation.

Lets say I calculated y for x (the results are shown in the code), and lets say every measurement has a +-2 error (STD), I found how to show it on the graph but didn't found how to include it in the calculation, so right now the STD is 0 and R^2 is 1 which obviously is wrong

How do I calculate and show the inaccuracy of the results?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
std = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=std, fmt='o', color='cadetblue', ecolor='red')

coef = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
poly1d_fn = np.poly1d(coef) 

plt.plot(x, poly1d_fn(x), '--k', label='linear fit')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=10)
plt.grid(color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.1)


linregress(x,y)
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: For the (x, y) data, std is 0 and slope is one. Your y is perfectly linear with x data

Comment: That's what the data show but it's a lie, in my example every measurement is +-2 off so it could be that first number in y is 3 and not 1. there is an uncertainty in the measurements and I don't know how to show it